# Pandas for Python: Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

Here's what I got from a tutorial

```
# Data Preprocessing

# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 3].values

# Taking care of missing data
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imputer = Imputer(missing_values = 'NaN', strategy = 'mean', axis = 0)
imputer = imputer.fit(X[:, 1:3])
X[:, 1:3] = imputer.transform(X[:, 1:3])

# Encoding categorical data
# Encoding the Independent Variable
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 0] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:, 0])
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
# Encoding the Dependent Variable
labelencoder_y = LabelEncoder()
y = labelencoder_y.fit_transform(y)
```

This is the X matrix with encoded dummy variables

```
1.000000000000000000e+00    0.000000000000000000e+00    0.000000000000000000e+00    4.400000000000000000e+01    7.200000000000000000e+04
0.000000000000000000e+00    0.000000000000000000e+00    1.000000000000000000e+00    2.700000000000000000e+01    4.800000000000000000e+04
0.000000000000000000e+00    1.000000000000000000e+00    0.000000000000000000e+00    3.000000000000000000e+01    5.400000000000000000e+04
0.000000000000000000e+00    0.000000000000000000e+00    1.000000000000000000e+00    3.800000000000000000e+01    6.100000000000000000e+04
0.000000000000000000e+00    1.000000000000000000e+00    0.000000000000000000e+00    4.000000000000000000e+01    6.377777777777778101e+04
1.000000000000000000e+00    0.000000000000000000e+00    0.000000000000000000e+00    3.500000000000000000e+01    5.800000000000000000e+04
0.000000000000000000e+00    0.000000000000000000e+00    1.000000000000000000e+00    3.877777777777777857e+01    5.200000000000000000e+04
1.000000000000000000e+00    0.000000000000000000e+00    0.000000000000000000e+00    4.800000000000000000e+01    7.900000000000000000e+04
0.000000000000000000e+00    1.000000000000000000e+00    0.000000000000000000e+00    5.000000000000000000e+01    8.300000000000000000e+04
1.000000000000000000e+00    0.000000000000000000e+00    0.000000000000000000e+00    3.700000000000000000e+01    6.700000000000000000e+04
```

The problem is **there are no column labels**. I tried

```
something = pd.get_dummies(X)
```

But I get the following Exception

```
Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most `sklearn` methods don't care about column names, as they're mainly concerned with the math behind the ML algorithms they implement.  You can add column names back onto the `OneHotEncoder` output after `fit_transform()`, if you can figure out the label encoding ahead of time.

First, grab the column names of your predictors from the original `dataset`, excluding the first one (which we reserve for `LabelEncoder`):

```
X_cols = dataset.columns[1:-1]
X_cols
# Index(['Age', 'Salary'], dtype='object')
```

Now get the order of the encoded labels.  In this particular case, it looks like `LabelEncoder()` organizes its integer mapping alphabetically:

```
labels = labelencoder_X.fit(X[:, 0]).classes_ 
labels
# ['France' 'Germany' 'Spain']
```

Combine these column names, and then add them to `X` when you convert to `DataFrame`:

```
# X gets re-used, so make sure to define encoded_cols after this line
X[:, 0] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:, 0])
encoded_cols = np.append(labels, X_cols)
# ...
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
encoded_df = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=encoded_cols)

encoded_df
   France  Germany  Spain        Age        Salary
0     1.0      0.0    0.0  44.000000  72000.000000
1     0.0      0.0    1.0  27.000000  48000.000000
2     0.0      1.0    0.0  30.000000  54000.000000
3     0.0      0.0    1.0  38.000000  61000.000000
4     0.0      1.0    0.0  40.000000  63777.777778
5     1.0      0.0    0.0  35.000000  58000.000000
6     0.0      0.0    1.0  38.777778  52000.000000
7     1.0      0.0    0.0  48.000000  79000.000000
8     0.0      1.0    0.0  50.000000  83000.000000
9     1.0      0.0    0.0  37.000000  67000.000000
```

**NB:** For example data I'm using [this dataset](https://github.com/franklinwillemen/Machine_Learning/blob/master/datapreprocessing/Dataset.csv), which seems either very similar or identical to the one used by OP. Note how the output is identical to OP's `X` matrix.